# How to make a save button

Tags: java, swing, save, jbutton, joptionpane

I am trying to make a save button but I don't know how to do it. I will explain a little bit about my program. When someone start the program it shows a JOptionPane and the user need to write a nickname and then when he clicks on OK button it saves his nickname in a text.file. This is a part from my code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;



public class SummerExamProject extends JFrame  {
   JButton Exit, About, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4;
   JPanel panel, panel2, panel3, panel4 ;

   public  SummerExamProject(){
        initUI();

    }

public void  initUI(){

    setTitle("Java");
    setSize(500, 450);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,8,9));




String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame1, " Enter a nickname ", "Nickname needed", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: You're good now. You have the nickname in `code`. Connect to a database like `sql` and store it.

Comment: Your question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501207/user-input-data-insert-into-a-sql-database).

Comment: What don't you know?  How to write to a file?  How to make a "save" button which is attached to an action which can do something when it's clicked?  How to manage the return results from the `JOptionPane`?

Comment: I havent used sql before. Is there some other way to store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store nickname to file you can use [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). Lets say you saved the nickname in `String` variable called nickname:

```
String nickname = "myAwesomeNickname";

try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:/nicknames.txt", true)));
    out.println(nickname);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling 
}
```

Comment: String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame1, " Enter a nickname: ", "Nickname needed", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); I want to save nicknames in this JoptionPane. Because in the code you  gave me you need to write your name in String nickname = " some nickname"; and

Comment: @Petur: Check CustomDialog dialog in swing tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("text.txt"));
        out.print(code);  // your String here
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    }
```

`text.txt` can also be a full path like `new FileOutputStream("D:/folder/text.txt")`
There are a few more options to write to files, though.